# Airflow distributed message flows with RabbitMQ message broker

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm a beginner in Apache Airflow. I have a requirement to scheduling tasks based on the JSON payload. Simply, that JSON payload contains the date and time and the required data to schedule the task. Can I accommodate this requirement using Apache Airflow? the simple architecture diagram that I want to implement is as follows.

[image]

As in the above diagram, I want to trigger a DAG with a JSON payload and schedule that data on a RabbitMQ broker according to the date and time in the payload. When the date and time condition met, the broker should pop that data from the queue and assign it to a worker node to execute (as distributed workers). So, inside the worker node, the **Python operator** can be used to invoke the backend.

Am I following the current path here? As per my understanding, RabbitMQ and worker node part is handled automatically by the **CeleryExecutor**. Can I schedule the tasks dynamically using another DAG in Airflow? Here I used the single file method to create dynamic DAGS on airflow.

**EDIT**

To accommodate the above requirement, I wrote a custom DAG as follow. But once I invoke it, it does not create the DAG called **my_scheduler**. Any idea?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime

def _schedule_task(*args):
    print('Task scheduling....')
        
def _create_dag(dag_id, schedule, default_args):
    dag = DAG(dag_id, schedule_interval=schedule, default_args=default_args)
    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='scheduler', python_callable=_schedule_task)
    return dag

def _training_model(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['dag_run'].conf)
    print("Triggered !!")
    dag_id = 'my_scheduler'
    default_args = {
                    'owner': 'airflow',
                    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1),
                    'catchup': False
                    }
    schedule = '@once'
    globals()[dag_id] = _create_dag(dag_id, schedule, default_args)
    print("Done !!")

with DAG("schedule_dag", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@once", catchup=False) as dag:

    training_model = PythonOperator(
        task_id="main_model",
        python_callable=_training_model
    )

    training_model
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the scheduling and execution part is handled by Airflow using CeleryExecutor (note: some suggest using Redis instead of RabbitMQ).

To pass JSON payload to your DAG you can utilise [DagRun conf](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run). Then your tasks within the DAG should reference the `conf` value either using [templated fields](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) (`{{ dag_run.conf }}`) or if you plan to use `PythonOperator` you can access the object directly:

```py
def python_callable(dag_run: DagRun):
  xyz = dag_run.conf["xyz"]  # this would be your JSON payload
  ...
```

> When the date and time condition met

Here I understand that you want to

1. Trigger the DAG via API with JSON payload
2. The DAG should not execute the PythonOperator logic instantly but wait for other conditions.

If that's true, then you can use sensor that will pause the execution until some conditions are met. In other words I would built the DAG as `check_conditions_sensor >> execute_work`.

### EDIT

Based on discussion in comment it seems that the author of the question wants to create a new DAG and schedule it using the values(date, time and interval) from the JSON payload.

To do that a DAG has to be created and that is not supported by Airflow REST API. DAG is a python file and it has to be uploaded to Airflow instance.

While generating a DAG is an easy part (for example by using jinja templates and generating python file), distribution of the DAG will be more tricky because it will depend on type of deployment and it also imposes some security risks.

I would done that by creating a `DAGFactory` DAG that would be called via Airflow REST API and would have build new DAGs using `dag_run.conf` passed in request. However, the resulting file generated by this DAG should uploaded to a place from where all other DAGs are distributed (git repo, S3 bucket, etc). Example below using [TaskFlow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html).

```py
@task
def get_template() -> str:
  # Here we get the template from remote so 
  # we can easily update it and version it
  return template

@task
def build_dag(template: str, dag_run: DagRun = None) -> str:
  dag_content = template.format(dag_run.conf)
  return dag_content

@task
def upload_dag(dag_content: str):
  # upload to gir repo, S3 etc so the DAg will be available in Airflow
  

with DAG("DAGFactory", ...) as dag:
  template = get_template()  
  dag_content = build_dag(template)
  upload_dag(dag_content)
```

Comment: Am I doing the flow in the correct way with Airflow? yes, I just want to trigger the DAG via API with the JSON payload. So https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run endpoint facilitates that. But how do I change the schedule_interval here? Let's say, I want to run my DAG in different schedules(cron, daily, once, etc.) so how do I configure this?

Comment: Triggering DAG via API has no schedule, it runs the DAG at once. If you want to run on schedule but with different configuration I would suggest to keep the configuration in some place (S3 bucket, repo or as an API endpoint) and then construct the DAG as `read_conf >> execute_logic` The configuration read in `read_conf` task can be passed via XCom to `execute_logic`. Please let me know if I should elaborate more then I will edit my answer.

Comment: it would be great if you can show me an example. let's assume I want it as API. so how would I do that? I have a DAG and I want to schedule it with an interval that comes with the JSON payload. JSON payload contains the date, time and interval of the task to be shduled.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you want the DAG to be executed only once at the given time from JSON payload or do you want to create each time a new DAG with different schedule?

Comment: For each request, I want to create a new DAG and schedule it using the values(date, time and interval) from the JSON payload.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you point me to why it is not working when I invoke the `schedule_dag` DAG using http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/schedule_dag/dagRuns API?

Comment: I tried a similar thing with subtags. But it doesn't create a separate DAG for me. Simply I just want to create a separate DAG upon my request for `schedule_dag`

Comment: This won't work because the DAG is never parsed by scheduler. To create a DAG you need to create python file that will be picked up by scheduler. For local, dev purposes you can  create DAG file by using `with open('path/to/dags/dag_name.py') as f: f.save(dag_content)`. [Here](https://github.com/PolideaInternal/airflow-munchkin/blob/master/airflow_munchkin/template/discovery/example_file.tpl) you can find an inspiration how a DAG can be created from template.